# How to measure a kubernetes container startup time?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I need this information to measure mean time to recovery (MTTR). I have tried using different kube-state-metrics but it does not seem to help much. Any hints on measuring MTTR will also be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You can use the pod status information, it records last transition time for each status signal. In this case you probably want the time difference between `PodScheduled` and `Ready`, but up to you to decide what counts as "startup time" or not (for example, does the time spent on pulling container images count?).

Comment: Hi..thanks for the reply. Is there a way to measure this using `kube-state-metrics`? I have information for `kube_pod_status_ready` and `kube_pod_status_scheduled` but not sure how to get the information about the transition time